# How to convert binary image to rgba image with transparent background in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Super simple question, I have a single channel image consisting of 0's and 255's and I would like to convert it into a 4 channel image of [0,0,0,0] and [255,255,255,255] in the most efficient manner possible. cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA causes the alpha to all be at 255 and np.where() feels like black magic to me so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner solution using cv2.merge function.

Let your input image be "img" which is of 1 channel.
To convert it to 4 channel, do this:

```py
img = cv2.merge((img.copy(), img.copy(), img.copy(), img.copy()))
```

Now the "img" will contain 4 channels and all the channels will be the same wrt values.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a numpy array with more layers and then change the values of this array to the values of your image.

```
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
h, w, d = img.shape #(217, 232, 3)

nr_of_new_layers = 1
alpha_img = np.zeros((h, w, d+nr_of_new_layers))

alpha_img[:,:,:3] = img  #alpha_img shape = (217, 232, 4)
```

Or if  there isn't any 3rd dimension then you can do

```
d = 0
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg', d)
h, w = img.shape #(217, 232)

nr_of_new_layers = 4
alpha_img = np.zeros((h, w, d+nr_of_new_layers))

alpha_img[:,:,d] = img  #alpha_img shape = (217, 232, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stack 4 copies of your single channel image with `np.dstack()`:

```
RGBA = np.dstack((im,im,im,im))            # or more tersely RGBA = np.dstack(([im]*4))
```

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np

# Make image
im = np.array([0,255,255,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Look at it:

```
array([  0, 255, 255,   0,   0], dtype=uint8)
```

Stack it depth-wise with `np.dstack()`:

```
RGBA = np.dstack((im,im,im,im))
```

Look at it:

```
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]]], dtype=uint8)
```